# Send arguments to callback method in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

So, i have two methods in class:

```
public function addSubpage( $page_title )
{
    $filtered_title = str_replace( " ", "_", strtolower( $page_title ) );
    add_submenu_page(
        $this->_menu_slug,
        $page_title,
        $page_title,
        $this->_capability,
        $filtered_title,
        array( $this, 'renderSubpage' )// Here i need send some data to renderSubpage method
    );
}
public function renderSubpage( $arg )
{
    var_dump( $arg ); // Here i need get this value
    include( 'views/plugin_heading.php' );
    include( 'views/form_create_argue.php' );
}
```

How can i send some data(s) from one method to another via callback?

Comment: That's generally not possible with the native `add_submenu_page` function, but as it's a class you can just store the data in a variable that is available to both methods.

Comment: Yea, i can add some props and assign they into method, but i dreaming for more dynamic approach =)